# Error: HTMLSpanElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, onclick

hola estoy intentando obtener el objeto `<span>` en javascript utilizando `onClick` pero al momento de dar click me aparece el siguiente error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: dat is not defined at HTMLSpanElement.onclick
```

el código que tengo es el siguiente, este es llamado desde un archivo `.js`:

```
window.onload = function () {
    counter = 0;
    for (initial = 0; initial < 5; initial++) {
        counter = counter + 1;
        $('#filename').append('' + counter + '<span class="fa fa-times-circle fa-lg closeBtn" onclick="dat(this)" title="remove"></span>');
    }
    function dat(myvalue) {
        console.log(myvalue);
    }
}
```

Desde mi `layout` llamo al archivo `external.js` que es donde está la función de esta manera:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
<script src="~/Public/js/External.js"></script>
```

mi `.css` es el siguiente:

```
#filename {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.5em;
}

.closeBtn:hover {
    color: red;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

a esto debería llegar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero al momento de dale click al `span` que es la "X", me manda el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

si alguien me puede ayudar con este error se lo agradezco de antemano

Comment: Tu código funciona a la perfección si se usa una estructura `html` apropiada. Se necesita más detalle para poder reproducir el problema, te invito a leer [mcve]. Hace falta ver cómo tienes organizado tu código `html` con respecto al código que muestras en tu pregunta. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras tiene razón en su comentario, el código anterior funciona. Puedes ver un ejemplo en [este jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/semagarcia/t61dexhg/8/)

Comment: ahí modifique el cuerpo del post. Efectivamente si funciona, ye he visto varios ejemplos de esa manera, pero cuando lo hago con un fichero externo como es en este caso en donde tengo todas las funciones necesarios, me manda ese error. Obviamente en mi fichero externo le he puesto el código js en primeras lineas para que no haya alguna otra función que impida que esta funcione

Comment: Mueve la definición de la función fuera del "onload", si la defines dentro no tienes acceso desde un nivel global como requiere el asignar las funciones de esa manera.

Comment: comprendo, ahí funciono, gracias por la ayuda :D

Comment: @FranciscoGarrido de todos modos me gustaría saber por que debe estar como función global y no dentro del "onload", ya que dentro del "onload" también tengo otras funciones similares de `onclick` y funcionan sin problemas

Comment: En el "onload" estas declarando una función anonima que contiene el código, al estar la función declarada dentro de esta, el scope donde existe es solamente dentro de la misma función de "onload", lo cual el elemento no tiene acceso a la función al no estar declarada de manera global. Puedes evitar esto asignando el evento mediante javascript en lugar de html.

Comment: ok, muchas gracias por tu respuesta :)